# Twitter Timeline Widget Vanishes with JQuery “Hide/Show”

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, twitter, widget

```
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Twitter</h2>
                <a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/Ollie_ODonnell" data-widget-id="557643946772664322">Tweets by @Ollie_ODonnell</a>
                <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
            <br><br><br>
        </div>
```

My website can be found here: [ollie-odonnell.com](http://ollie-odonnell.com)

On my website I have a little JavaScript/JQuery function to allow the user to "slide" between pages. That means that it uses JQuery Hide and JQuery Show.

When the page opens directly to the "about" page, the Twitter "recent tweets" widget loads, but as soon as it is hidden and re-shown, the widget refuses to load. What can I do to fix this?

More info:

- https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines <-- I followed the instructions here, and re-copied and pasted the snippet many times (you can see it above).

Comment: Would also like to know!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be associated with the use of the jQuery UI slide function. It works fine with the standard jQuery hide() and show(). See the following jsfiddle. Try the "Hide" and "Show" first and then try the "Hide using jQuery UI Slide" and "Show using jQuery UI Slide".

http://jsfiddle.net/ossuf5ov/4/

```
$('#showjQueryUI').click(function(){
    $('#twitter').show("slide",{direction: 'right'},400);
});

$('#hidejQueryUI').click(function(){
    $('#twitter').hide("slide",{direction: 'left'},400);
});


$('#show').click(function(){
    $('#twitter').show();
});

$('#hide').click(function(){
    $('#twitter').hide();
});
```